# How to check if file exists in a folder, if not move onto next folder to check php

Tags: php, html

I'm having an array of variable which will retrieve all user images name in my database.

$userdetail['user_image'] => it will print all the images name form my database, these images locations are from three different folder

Location-1 : admin/assets/images/admin/[All Admin Images]

Location-2 : vendor/assets/images/vendor/[All Vendor Images]

Location-3 : customer/assets/images/Customer/[All Customer Images]

**Main page**

```
<?php foreach ($userdetails as $key => $userdetail): ?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $userdetail['username']; ?></td>
         
         <td>
         <!-- if the filename Exist in Admin Folder -->
             <img src="<?php echo'assets/images/admin/'.$userdetail['user_image'];              ?>"style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
         <!-- if the filename Exist in Vendor Folder -->
             <img src="<?php echo'assets/images/vendor/'.$userdetail['user_image'];              ?>"style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
         <!-- if the filename Exist in Customer Folder -->
          <img src="<?php echo'assets/images/customer/'.$userdetail['user_image'];              ?>"style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
               
        </td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I want a solution to check all these three folder with my variable $userdetail['user_image'].

Comment: _“I want a solution”_ - then I’d suggest you start writing one :-) Where is the actual problem? Put your base paths into an array that you can loop over, inside the loop append your file name and check if the result actually exists. If so, break out of your loop after that.

Comment: `file_exists()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($userdetails as $key => $userdetail): ?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $userdetail['username']; ?></td>
         <td>
<?php
    foreach(
      [
        'admin/assets/images/admin/' => 'admin',
        'vendor/assets/images/vendor/' => 'vendor',
        'customer/assets/images/Customer/' => 'customer',
      ] as $path => $stub
    ) {
      $filename = $path . $userdetail['user_image']; // e.g. admin/assets/images/vendor/foobar.jpg
      $url = 'assets/images/' . $stub . '/' . $userdetails['user_image']; // e.g. assets/images/vendor/foobar.jpg

      if ( file_exists( $filename ) ) {
?>
             <img src="<?= $url ?>" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
<?php
        break;
      }
    }
?>
        </td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```